# Clone only a particular release from the git repository

Tags: git, github, tags, release, git-clone

I want to clone only the release "Caffe_v1.1.4" from the GIT repository https://github.com/intel/caffe . could you please let me know the script to use to copy the content into the local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows open `https://github.com/intel/caffe/archive/1.1.4.tar.gz` in your browser

for linux OS `curl -s https://github.com/intel/caffe/archive/1.1.4.tar.gz` should work

## UPDATE

Windows powershell

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12' //for https support 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
Invoke-WebRequest http://github.com/intel/caffe/archive/1.1.4.zip -OutFile yourpath\caffe.zip
```

Comment: I want to use the command in the shell script to clone the release content fro repo into local folder on the disk. How should i change the command?.

Answer (score 0):

By "clone", if you mean "git clone" the repository,

```
 git clone -b 1.1.4 --single-branch https://github.com/intel/caffe.git
```

You can also add the option `--depth=1` to minimize the size of fetched data.

If you mean "download" the source code,

```
curl -LOk https://github.com/intel/caffe/archive/1.1.4.zip
unzip 1.1.4.zip -d foo
```